# Spurious 0.0000000000001 added to formula result

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, office365

My wife and I have a spreadsheet to work out our finances at the beginning of each month and this month has a strange figure in cell `F9`.

The formula in cell `F9` is `="+ £"&-'Sue''s Outgoings'!C13&" Shortfall"` which should output `+ £57.35 Shortfall` but it outputs `+ £57.3500000000001 Shortfall`.

**Formula in cell `F9`**
[image: image of formula in cell F9]

To try and troubleshoot this, I put `=-'Sue''s Outgoings'!C13` in cell `F13` which outputs exactly what is in `'Sue''s Outgoings'!C13` which is 57.35. (see second image below)

**Formula in cell `F13`**
[image: image of formula in cell F13]

All cells in `Sue's Outgoings` sheet are formatted to `Currency` format and I temporarily reformatted all cells to `General` to see if there was a hidden strange figure in there and there was nothing. All figures in `Sue's Outgoings` sheet are straight figures and not results of formulae.

What other reason could there be for the spurious addition of 0.0000000000001 to the result?

Comment: because Excel uses floating-point math. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/995714)

Comment: @phuclv https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MathematiciansAnswer

Comment: It's precisely the same reason that 2/3 is sometimes reported as 0.666666667 -- a tiny bit more than the actual value when converted into decimal.

Comment: Not at all @DavidSchwartz  - money added together in decimal results in a maximum of 2 decimal places. Fact! Whether it is 0.33 or 0.50. If I was dividing money in 3rds or more I would give you that. But as pointed out in the question, the result being pulled was a straight `SUM()`.

Comment: Your comment to @DavidSchwartz makes it clear that you do not understand that Excel calculates in floating point, associates that value to the cell, then applies formatting when displaying that value.  Your cell, `"+ £"&-'Sue''s Outgoings'!C13&" Shortfall"` fetches the value, not the displayed form, immediately stringifies it for concatenation, then applies its cell's formatting.  See the `DOLLAR` function as an example of converting a value to a currency formatted string.

Comment: @EricTowers I do understand. Look at ALL of the comments, not just one!

Comment: @ChrisRogers : I'm looking at **all** the comments.  You keep presenting surprise that floating point is being used for currecny calculations and that you believe currency formatting on `'Sue''s Outgoings'!C13` has any impact on the stringification.  Cell formatting only affects presentation; it has nothing to do with the computation.

Comment: @EricTowers my very first comment is under the accepted answer saying *"Wow! Never thought of binary affecting decimal based calculations in software. I of course knew of the issues of binary and decimal based figure when talking about hard drive space. https://www.tetrabytes.co.uk/the-hard-drive-storage-swindle/ "* Obviously, as pointed out after, it is a bit of a different thing, but I do understand binary calculations.

Comment: @ChrisRogers : As you commented about an hour ago: "money added together in decimal results in a maximum of 2 decimal places. Fact! Whether it is 0.33 or 0.50. If I was dividing money in 3rds or more I would give you that. But as pointed out in the question, the result being pulled was a straight SUM()."  And that `SUM` was of floating point values, represented internally as binary.  The *value*s of several cells in your computation are *not* the value you are seeing -- you actually saw one when you stringified it, rather than forcing cell formatting to hide reality from you.

Comment: @EricTowers actually no string formatting hides it. It is automatically formatted by Excel correctly. See the Microsoft link in the accepted answer. You can have it in General or Text format at it will be in 2 decimal places as pointed out in my question. It is strangely pulled unformatted, which is the problem, but it can be rectified following either of 2 methods pointed out by Microsoft. If you follow the thread under the accepted answer you would see I just didn't realise that floating point math errors would affect Excel as I naively thought they would account for it in the source code.

Comment: @ChrisRogers : All cell **values** are unformatted.  All cell values used in formulas are unformatted.  All computation is unformatted.  Formatting only occurs during presentation.  Your confusion is "you do not understand that Excel calculates in floating point, associates that value to the cell, then applies formatting when displaying that value."  That your formatting of prior cells has completely blinded you to what is occurring in your computation is what you have shown in your question.

Comment: I don't have a copy of Excel ready to try, but even this floating point calculation can be inaccurate (should be 0.3): `=""&(0.1+0.1+0.1)`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Just count in cents and everything will be OK, unless you're computing interests or other things like that where you end up with fraction of cents.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh. That link explains in great detail exactly where the ....0001 comes from, so no, not at all.

Comment: Back in the day, several programmers became extremely rich by funneling off "invisible" rounding errors in financial applications into their own accounts. Never round intermediate results because then the differences get magnified by subsequent calculations.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Excel uses floating point math, that means sometimes there are such digits hidden in your values. (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result)

Those are generally displayed correctly, however when you convert them to text, those indeed may cause issues, one workaround is to use ROUND in your formula:

```
="+ £"& ROUND(-'Sue''s Outgoings'!C13,2) &" Shortfall"
```

Comment: Wow! Never thought of binary affecting decimal based calculations in software. I of course knew of the issues of binary and decimal based figure when talking about hard drive space. https://www.tetrabytes.co.uk/the-hard-drive-storage-swindle/

Comment: That's a slightly different thing, mind..

Comment: Agreed, @CaiusJard

Comment: @ChrisRogers actually decimal based calculations are nearly non existing in computers. They almost always use binary and just read or display them in decimal.

Comment: I agree with you there too @jjj. I just didn't think of the possibility that floating point math errors could affect a major piece of software like Excel.  Just goes to show that you cannot always rely on the software working as expected.

Comment: @ChrisRogers - it is working as expected, as long as you expect computers to use floating point maths and therefore have limitations in talking down to us dumb humans in decimal. Lot of decimal numbers which seem "simple" to us cannot be represented properly in binary, just like 1/3 cannot be represented properly as a decimal number. If you were treating this as a number, Excel would deal with the issue and you would not get to see the problem, as proved by your third screenshot where Excel hides the discrepancy from you. Because you are showing numbers as text, that code did not kick in here.

Comment: @ChrisRogers yeah, this is a common thing in programming. I've seen small rounding errors like this, multiplied by large volumes of stock being purchased causing some quite outlandish calculations :)

Comment: There's a reason why money in particular is often handled by using integers scaled by a factor of 100 or by storing the fractional part separately ( [database example](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html) ). That has its own set of problems, but floating-point isn't one.

Comment: @AC Or, historically, by using BCD (and indirectly making interoperability remarkably more complicated by inventing EBCDIC as a result...).

Comment: @AC Yup.  If you don't store your money in pennies (or whatever the smallest unit is for your currency) you're going to have accountants after you with pitchforks.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Or now using exact numbers - the actual name depends on the language but in essence thjey act like BCD

Comment: In an older Indian currency system they had 1 Pice = 1/4 Anna = 1/64 Rupee. Probably not to avoid floating-point problems though.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn I had no idea EBCDIC was based on BCD, even though it's right there in the name.  Thanks for the history lesson.

Answer (score 14):

To add a fix rather than a workaround to the problem, following the [Microsoft Docs page linked by @MátéJuhász](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result):

If you are working on spreadsheets which are purely money based like am here, or anything else to one fixed number of decimal places, you could set the worksheet to "precision as displayed".

> ### Method 2: Precision as displayed
>
> In some cases, you may be able to prevent rounding errors from affecting your work by using the **Precision as displayed** option. This option forces the value of each number in the worksheet to be the displayed value. To turn on this option, follow these steps.
>
> 1. On the **File** menu, click **Options**, and then click the **Advanced** category.
> 2. In the **When calculating this workbook** section, select the workbook that you want, and then select the **Set precision as displayed** check box.
>
> For example, if you choose a number format that shows two decimal places, and then you turn on the **Precision as displayed** option, all accuracy beyond two decimal places is lost when you save your workbook. This option affects the active workbook including all worksheets. You cannot undo this option and recover the lost data. We recommend that you save your workbook before you enable this option.

Then there is no need to worry about floating point math errors needing to be worked around with `ROUND()`.

Comment: The explanation in this answer is exactly backwards.  The setting being recommended injects errors into calculated values.

Comment: Not at all @EricTowers - As Microsoft say, it would reduce calculation accuracy by 2 decimal places as the figures would be automatically rounded.

Comment: Rounding is the process of replacing a correct value with an incorrect value.  You are recommending inserting error into computations to resolve a formatting issue.

Comment: @EricTowers now you are not understanding the correction of floating point errors. Take the result and round it to 2 decimal places. You get the result expected. Again, I understand that is done front-end in the usual sense and back-end in the file and sheet coding will be the "accurate" number according to binary calculations otherwise finer accuracy cannot be maintained with higher decimal place figures. We will have to beg to differ with each other I believe as you think I don't understand when I know I do

Comment: "You get the result expected."  No.  You **see** the result expected.  The value in your spreadsheet is now wrong.

Comment: It depends on what type of calculation you’re doing. If all you’re doing is adding, subtracting and multiplying by integers, then rounding to 2 decimal places for currency is fine. As soon as you start doing calculations that include fractions of a penny, you will lose that information and introduce error. I think it’s better that the decision to round is explicit in the formula. Of course, you also need to consider the potential biases introduced by always rounding 0.5 upwards (as Excel does).

Answer (score 9):

You are asking Excel to display a number in the middle of a text string without telling it what format to use or in any other way prompting it to realise you might want it to figure out how best to display this.

Rounding is an option here, but generally I think it is good practice here to just unambiguously tell Excel how you would like this number to appear in the middle of this text (I am using a simple two decimal places format here:

```
="+ £"& TEXT(-'Sue''s Outgoings'!C13,"#.00") &" Shortfall"
```

Alternatively, you could do the whole thing just by pulling the number in and using a custom number format like this (note it displays both positive and negative numbers as positive, with different labels):

```
+ £#,###.00 "excess";+ £#,###.00 "shortfall";0.00 "balanced";@
```

Comment: Hmmm, I can see where you are coming from, but when all the figures in a table are entered as figures, and not formulas, plus the figures entered are all to 2 decimal figures, the result of a `SUM()` total should be in **a maximum** of 2 decimal figures. I can understand that I might get 1 or zero decimal places, (e.g. £0.25 + £0.75 = £1) but 13 decimal places? Therefore having a figure at 13 decimal figures is not what you would expect if the calculations are done correctly.  Hence, the answer given by @MátéJuhász

Comment: Because even entering only one decimal place can result in a binary number which is really long and still inaccurate. Eg 0.1 (1/10) is 0.00011001100110011001100110011 in binary to 29 bits of precision and still not very close: 0.099999999627471.
"Precision as displayed" is great if everything is always entered as data, or not calculated with any more precision (eg always adding/subtracting, never dividing or multiplying by non-integers.

Comment: @ChrisRogers What would you expect 1/3 to be displayed as? What if 35/100 has no exact representation in the internal format the computer uses just as 1/3 has no exact representation in fixed-precision base 10 decimal?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz why are you talking of 3rds? Where is it mentioned that 3rds or even 35/100 were involved?

Comment: @ChrisRogers 57.35 is 57 and 35/100. It's easier for humans to understand thirds because they likely have some experience with representing 1/3 and 0.333333 and 2/3 and 0.666667 such that 2 * 1/3 doesn't produce precisely 2/3 and so on.

Comment: This answer could use more information on *why* this happens—answers should be independent—but ultimately, +1 regardless: This is the correct solution to the problem.

Comment: The more interesting question is "why does this not happen more often?" people often use numbers on the assumption they are stored as literally the value that was input, and expect to display them without explicit type casting and get desired results - and most of the time, that miracle actually happens! 
The extra code underlying this to hide or correct for these rounding errors all the time is quite frankly incredible, and without it we would need a whole SE forum just for "Floating Point Calculation Errors"

Answer (score 1):

Long ago, computer programmers decided to not store decimal numbers perfectly.

***Theoretically***, the square root of two can be stored in a computer.
This is for the same reason that when you use a pen and paper to write the following symbol, it does ***NOT*** require an infinite amount of paper and ink.

[image: SQUARE_ROOT_OF_TWO]

In practice, computer programmers do not use precise decimal numbers. As such, every time that you add, subtract, multiply, or divide, you introduce rounding error.

If you want to learn more, you can Google for "IEEE single precision floating point number."